# Access denied when starting systemd service

Tags: raspbian, python, sudo, init.d, systemd

Noob question, but hopefully someone can help me out here.  I'm transitioning from init.d to systemd on my RPi running Linux, as I'm told it would cut my boot time in half.

My init script *requires sudo* as it needs to access GPIO components.

### init.d service

My `/etc/init.d/hue` command looked like this before:

`sudo python /home/pi/hue/app.py`

### systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=Hue Controller

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=sudo /usr/bin/python /home/pi/hue/app.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `$ systemctl start hue.service` the following error message:

`Failed to issue method call: Access denied`

I've been tinkering with things for hours now and I haven't gotten around this issue.  I've tried putting the ExecStart script in another bash file and pointing to that, changing my etc/sudoers to allow all for root, but nothing is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not sudo systemctl start hue.service?  I've not noticed systemd making any difference to my boot times.  I have a fairly standard system and it still takes 45 seconds before my userland stuff starts on the Pi.

Comment: Agree w/ joan that systemd will probably not make such a big difference to boot times on a single core system (I haven't noticed one either).  It is somewhat nicer to use than the old debian twist on SysV though.

Comment: Note that further questions about systemd are more appropriate to the [Unix & Linux Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Init services run as root.  **Do not include `sudo` in service files run by init**, regardless of whether it is SysV or systemd.

I would try *[but please see comments, this is a bit personal preference]*:

```
[Unit]
Requires=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/pi/bin/hue.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then in `/home/pi/bin/hue.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
python /home/pi/hue/app.py &> /dev/null &
```

Note the `&` at the end to ensure this forks, since we have said this is `forking`.  If `app.py` does this itself (i.e., daemonizes), you could invoke it directly from `ExecStart`.

You might prefer to replace `&> /dev/null` w/ `&> /tmp/app.py.log` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Just a note, it needs to have ```[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target``` at the end of the service file or it will throw an error.

Also, what does ```local-fs.target``` mean for "Requires" and "After"?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's not complete -- I meant I'd include at least those fields and try `forking` instead of `simple`.  WRT to `local-fs.target`, this is to make sure it's run after the root filesystem is mounted read-write.  Most things do, but without that there's no guarantee.

Comment: A lot of the changes you recommended are not necessary.  systemd does _not_ require that services fork, in fact it's much easier with systemd to not fork, just keep the service type simple.  Also, don't bother redirecting the output to /dev/null or to a file, systemd automatically collects all of that and stores it in the journal so that you can see what's going on with your service.

The only change that was really needed was dropping the sudo from the ExecStart.

Comment: @jccollie I admit my understanding of systemd is far from perfect and you are certainly correct by the man page -- I think I came to use this model via experimentation and it has been the most foolproof one for me; I've been through some personal frustration getting plain jane services such as this to work under systemd (I still like it more than SysV though)...

Comment: ...However, I don't think "not necessary" amounts to incorrect/inefficient/somehow problematic here though (beyond an extra shell that could be fixed with `exec`), so I've let it stand but removed the "must fork" bit and added a reference to these comments.  Thank you for your answer, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

The only change that should be necessary is to drop the sudo from the ExecStart line:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hue Controller

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/hue/app.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```